# My useContext hook is not working, am unable to find error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-context

It is my next.js project
I have separately made the useContext  folder and there I wrote my object or data which  I want to use by my every files or components , and to do so I enclosed my _app.js file with the context one, but when I am using it in my one of the page, it showing undefined error. Unable to understand
Below am sending my every bit of fies

useContext/useContextherehere.js

```
import React, { createContext, useContext} from 'react';

const UserContext = createContext();

const UseContexthere = ({children}) => {
    const biodata = {
        name : "Manish",
        profession : "Coder & Rapper",
        age : 25
    }
  return (
    <>
      <UserContext.Provider value={{biodata}}>
          {children}
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </>
  )
}

export default UseContexthere;
```

_app.js -- in next.js

```
import '@/styles/globals.css';
import UseContexthere from './useContext/useContexthere';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <UseContexthere>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
  </UseContexthere>
  )

}
```

about.js -- using here my context thing

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import UseContexthere from './useContext/useContexthere';


const About = () => {
    const user = useContext(UseContexthere);
  return (
    <div>
        <div>
            <h3>Following data is coming through useContext Hook</h3>
            <p>Hey my name is {user.name}</p>
            
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default About
```

but than it showing me error of undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `{{biodata}}` seems odd. So maybe use `user.biodata.name`? or remove the extra brackets?

Comment: You're not using the correct import in `useContext`

Answer (score 2):

### Edit:

Here's a NextJS stackblitz of the details of this answer:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-esbbm1?file=pages%2Findex.js

### Answer:

It's because you're not using the correct import

You need to export the actual context (not just your provider component):

```
export const UserContext = createContext();
```

and in your consuming component you need to use that export, **not** the default export:

```
import { UserContext } from './useContext/useContexthere';


...

    const user = useContext(UserContext);
```

In practice, what is common in React applications is the hook is also exported from the place the context is created, just to keep things simpler:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext} from 'react';

const UserContext = createContext();

// now just import this hook in your component
export const useUserContext = () => React.useContext(UserContext)

...
```

This is in addition to the typos details by the other answers

Comment: I did all things still showing undefined
/// useContexthere
import React, { createContext, useContext} from 'react';
export const UserContext = createContext();
const UseContexthere = ({children}) => {
    const biodata = { name : "Manish", profession : "Coder & Rapper", age : 25    }
  return (
    <>
      <UserContext.Provider value={biodata}>
          {children}
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </>
  )
}
export default UseContexthere;

Comment: //about.js
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import UseContexthere from './useContext/useContexthere';
const About = ({data, abt}) => {
    const user = useContext(UseContexthere);
  return (
    <div>
            <h3>Following data is coming through useContext Hook</h3>
            <p>Hey my name is {user.name}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default About;

Comment: @Manish - debug yourself a bit, add a console.log(user) in your component after your hook and see what’s in there

Comment: Its not working, still. I checked thoroughly

Comment: @Manish - what is in the console.log? Please add more debugging details or a reproduible example

Answer (score 0):

```
<UserContext.Provider value={{biodata}}>
```

```
<p>Hey my name is {user.name}</p>
```

You are creating an object with a `biodata` property, but then you are trying to access a name property. To fix this, either change the provided value to be just the biodata object, not nested inside another object:

```
<UserContext.Provider value={biodata}>
```

Or change the way you consume the context to expect the `biodata` property:

```
<p>Hey my name is {user.biodata.name}</p>
```

Comment: Surely this is a typo then?

Answer (score 0):

This is what is essentially happening because of double curly braces.

```js
const biodata = {
        name : "Manish",
        profession : "Coder & Rapper",
        age : 25
    }

let x = {biodata};

console.log(x);
```

You are not passing `biodata`, but an object which has `biodata` as a key.
Just update your code like:

```
<UserContext.Provider value={biodata}>
          {children}
      </UserContext.Provider>
```

Comment: I did all things still showing undefined /// useContexthere import React, { createContext, useContext} from 'react'; export const UserContext = createContext(); const UseContexthere = ({children}) => { const biodata = { name : "Manish", profession : "Coder & Rapper", age : 25 } return ( <> <UserContext.Provider value={biodata}> {children} </UserContext.Provider> </> ) } export default UseContexthere

Comment: //about.js import React, {useContext} from 'react'; import UseContexthere from './useContext/useContexthere'; const About = ({data, abt}) => { const user = useContext(UseContexthere); return ( <div> <h3>Following data is coming through useContext Hook</h3> <p>Hey my name is {user.name}</p> </div> ) } export default About